# Image Recognition - Classifying an image in an image (i.e classify an object based on surrounding objects)?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm kind of new to this image classification stuff so this is a somewhat high-level question. I was wondering if it's possible to train an image classifier (i.e using just TF/Keras or one of the many image recognition libraries and APIs) to identify whether an object is in an object. For example:

[Output: A square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s5yN.png)

[Output: A circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf9qi.png)

[Output: A circle in a square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf8vY.png)

[Output: A square in a circle in a square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQU7F.png)

[Output: A square in a circle and a square in a square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moQTn.png)

...and so on

If it's possible, what's the best way to go about it? Do I have to train the model to recognize all the variations example by example (which is unfavorable as there are far too many potential examples), or is there some better way? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using simpler computer vision techniques instead of going for machine learning.
For example, if you use OpenCV, it has an inbuilt function called findContours, which returns a hierarchy.

Example:

[image]

The matrix on top shows how each shape is related to other, according to -

[Next, Previous, First_Child, Parent]

For instance, contours 2 and 4 (circle and rectangle) are at the same level. Hence in the matrix, the next of the second row is 4. You can construct a tree like this to get the output as you desired. You just need to make sure that the inner and outer contours of single shape are not counted as two separate ones which I didn't do here so it shows 5,7 in the output.

Comment: Thanks, amazing and detailed answer (would upvote if I could :) ) I've been reading on contours and apparently it works best for white on black images, and I was wondering what parameters you used for canny edge detection to get such crisp lines?

Comment: It's not canny edge. Simple thresholding based on gray scale values would work. Even if you have color image, convert it to gray scale. You can accept this as answer if it helped